# what is the sizeof this structure ? and why?

Tags: c

the following program gives output 4. I thought it will output 8 sizeof(int) + sizeof(unsigned int)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
        struct node
        {
                int a;
                struct node * next;
        };
        struct node * p= (struct node *) malloc( sizeof( struct node));
        printf("%d", sizeof( p));
}
```

Comment: You're taking the size of the pointer instead of the object itself.

Comment: It's also important to know if you're compiling this for 32-bits or 64-bits, as that makes a difference as to how large the `int` and pointers are.

Answer (score 2):

In this code, `p` is a pointer, so you're just printing the size of a pointer (which is apparently 4 bytes in your compiler/OS combination). If you want the size of the structure, you need to print `sizeof(*p)`. Also, as was pointed out, using "%d" for a `size_t` won't necessarily work ("%zu" is correct, although %d will on most compilers/OSs in the real world). Also, you shouldn't assume that the size of the structure "should" be 8. Pointers might be bigger, or the compiler might want to pad or align the structure in some odd way.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is just a *pointer*. Its size depends on ABI, which is in your case **4**.

Comment: No, it will be the size of a pointer, which may or may not be the size of an unsigned int.

Comment: You're right that it's the size of the pointer. You're wrong to assume what that size is.

Answer (score 1):

And the **correct** answer: your output, if any, is indeterminate, because you're using the wrong format specifier in the call to `printf()`. You should have used `%zu` instead - `sizeof()` yields an object of type `size_t`.

Thus, your program invokes **undefined behavior,** and it's free to do (and print) anything it wants to.

Comment: I believe converting an unsigned int to int will not result in undefined behavior. It might convert some thing like 255 into something like -127 on 8 bit systems. Not sure though. A source to the undefined behaviour would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The point is that `sizeof(x)` doesn't yield an `unsigned int`, it yields a `size_t`. On most systems, that's the same as an `unsigned int`, but it's not required to be. `%zu` is the proper format specifier for a `size_t`, whereas `%d` may cause terrible things to happen.